# Unable to show data in ExtJS Tree Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-grid, extjs-stores

I just copied the [example of ExtJS tree grid](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/example/tree/treegrid.html) from Sencha's site. I created a fiddle with only difference being, I am using local data instead of using proxy & I have removed some columns.

Please check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1v5) and tell me why I am not able to see data in the grid?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tree stores don't have a `data` option (search for it in [the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-cfg-folderSort)). Memory proxies, on the other hand, do. So you can put your data in it to solve your problem:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'Task',
    proxy: {
        data: JData,
        type: 'memory'
    },
    folderSort: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I have added the data under the root property of the store and got the desired result. Many Thanks !!!